Linq query in c#, Find the previous date
I have a list of stored values where one of their attributes is a date. I am trying to use a Linq query in C# to find the most recent date with respect to my targetDate. So for instance, let's say the stored values in a sql database with their date columns being:  01/05/2024, 04/04/2024, and 06/17/2024. Then say my target date is 03/10/2024. I need my code to find the values with 01/05/2024, because technically 04/04/2024 hasn't happened for the targetDate yet, even though it is closer. Then if my next target date is 05/22/24, I need it to find just the values with 04/04/2024 as their date.
This is a rough sketch, but not the entirety of my code:
public async Task<List<index>> Get(DateTime targetDate, int numberofValues) {
    DateTime loggedDate;

    var dateList = await _dbContext.database
        .Where(targetDate <= DateTime.Now)
        .Select(targetDate).Distinct().ToListAsync();

    var lastDate = dateList.OrderBy(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks)).Last();
    var firstDate = dateList.OrderBy(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks)).First();

    if (listofvalues > 0) {
        if (firstDate > targetDate)                
        {
            await _dbContext
                .database
                .Where(loggedDate == lastDate)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await _dbContext
                .database
                .Where(loggedDate == firstDate)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}

Currently it can only handle two sets of values with different dates. I need it to be able to handle multiple.

So you need the row having the most recent date <= the target date. I do not see a need to prefetch all of the dates ahead of time. Given a date/time targetDate, you can use the LINQ query var latestEligableRow = _dbContext.database.Where(d => d.loggedDate <= targetDate).OrderByDescending(d => d.loggedDate).FirstOrDefault();. This will efficiently retrieve the row you need, provided that loggedDate is indexed. If no eligible row is found, the result is null.  The equivalent SQL would be SELECT TOP 1 D.* FROM [database] D WHERE D.loggedDate <= @targetDate ORDER BY D.loggedDate DESC.

I was unclear about the object names used in your code above. database is a very confusing name for a table, and it wasn't clear wherher that table contained a column named targetDate or loggedDate. The syntax in your posted code is also off: .Where() and .Seklect() typically accept lambda functions, but your code just has ordinary expressions. Should .Where(targetDate <= DateTime.Now) be .Where(d => d.loggedDate <= DateTime.Now)? Should .Select(targetDate) be .Select(d => d.loggedDate)?

If you tag your question with the ORM (such as entity-framework or entity-framework-core) and the DBMS (such as sql-server or mysql) you question will reach a wider audience.

I would suggest to change the date representations in the question from MM/dd/YYYY to YYYY/MM/dd, because the former can't be easily differentiated from the dd/MM/YYYY, which is a common representation in many cultures.

You wrote: 
"I am trying to use a Linq query in C# to find the most recent date with respect to my targetDate."
Later it appears that you want the highest date smaller than a given date, not the most recent one

Requirement: given a DateTime, and an IQueryable sequence objects where every object has a property that returns a DateTime, give me (the DateTime value of) the object with the highest value of DateTime that is smaller or equal to the given DateTime.

To make it simple, I assume that you know what kind of items are in your table. For instance Students, but it might be Products, Appointments, whatever.
class Student
{
    public DateTime Birthday {get; set;}
    ...    // other properties
}

IQueryable<Student> students = dbContext.Students;  // your Students table

DateTime limitDate = ...  // the given DateTime

How about this:
// fetch the youngest student that is older than LimitDate
// = Student with highest value for Birthday, still smaller than LimitDate
Student YoungestStudentWithBirthDayBeforeLimitDate = dbContext.Students

    // keep only Students with a Birthday smaller than limitDate:
    .Where(student => student.Birthday < limitDate)

    // order them by Descending value for Birthday
    .OrderByDescending(student => student.BirthDay)

    // now the youngest student is the first one
    .FirstOrDefault();

If you are not interested in Students, but only in the value of the date you don't need to Sort, it is enough to select the largest Birthday that is still smaller than limitDate:
DateTime youngestBirthDayOlderThanLimitDate = dbContext.Students
    .Select(student => student.BirthDay)
    .MaxOrDefault();

If your entity framework version does not support Max, you should Sort:
DateTime youngestBirthDayOlderThanLimitDate = dbContext.Students
    .Where(student => student.BirthDay <= limitDate)
    .OrderByDescending(student => student.Birthday)
    .Select(student => student.BirthDay)
    .FirstOrDefault();

Of course you can do the Select before the Where. This doesn't change a lot in efficiency. However, it is important that you do the Where before the Sorting, thus limiting the number of items to sort.
